# cast attribute in c++

Tags: c++, attributes, casting

In my program I get a string, which consists of the attribute name and attribute value. For Example: `string X 2`. My problem is, that I have a lot of attributes and they have different types. It could be int, boolean or enumeration. For example, `X 2` should be `int x = 2;` `STATUS 0` should be `bool status = false` and so on.

So I need to read the string and create the attribute with the value which depends of the string. I thought about the hash_map, but maybe you have another idea?

I also don't know how I can put the Type of the attribute in hash_map.
Something like this:

```
typedef unordered_map<string, type> MapType;
```

I know how the hash_map works with the function pointer; maybe there is something for the type.  That can give me a reference, for example, to int, bool, and than I can search the map and cast the value from my string.

Comment: New sentences start with capital letter.

Comment: it's not so easy to answer because it involves semantics: "STATUS 0" why a bool status = false and not an integer int status = 0?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov if it bothers you that much, the edit button is right there.

Comment: How is the type of the attribute determined from the string? What do you want to do once the attributes are created from those strings? How are they used? You should ask about the problem that you want to solve --i.e. store a generic configuration in a text file, rather than about some implementation detail

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: :) Interestingly capital letters use to mark the beginning of a sentence are a quite recent addition to languages, probably no more than 300 years old in natural language. In programming languages, some are still waiting to catch up... I have not seen a common pattern of starting expressions with capital letters in C++, for example...

Comment: While there has been computing involving electronic computers, English has always used capital letters at the beginning of a sentence.  And also for the personal pronoun 'I'.  StackOverflow is supposed to use English.  It is annoying to fix up postings by people whose shift key is broken, or just functions erratically.

Comment: Common, downvoters, give some space here... This is his first question in SO, let him/her try and fix the issues before jumping over! (not that it matters much, downvoting when a person has only 1 rep point will not have much effect on the user, other than moral: *I cannot ask in SO, people will violently downvote and possibly even close the question!*)

Comment: I didn't get the relation - C++ and English :D Anyway, IMO, it's quite  disrespectfully to ask someone for help and show that you, by yourself, are not ready to show some effort and at least, try to format your post and use capital letters (I'm not talking about perfect English, we're all from different countries here, but I doubt that 4eloveg's language does not use capital letters)

Comment: i see, that most of people spend time here to criticise a post and not to help. :-P

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `map<string, string>` type to store the attributes as you load/read them from the strings such as "X 2" or "STATUS 0". Next, write a class e.g. AttributesContainer that acts as a wrapper for the map, with methods as `getString(string key)`, `getInt(string key)`, and `getBoolean(string key)`, etc.

So, depending on the caller and the called get method, you can interpret the value from the map depending on your preferred logic. You will be free to interpret 0/1 as boolean if getBoolean is called, but return int 0 or 1 if getInt gets called.

Comment: I think this is the closest answer so far to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Getting values of different types (boolean, integer, string...) from configuration file or something is a problem that has been already solved many times... maybe too many times :)

Have a look how it's done at [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html), [cfgparser](http://cfgparser.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cfgparser/trunk/include/cfgparser.h?revision=17&view=markup), [IniReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IniReader.aspx), ...

Comment: yeah, but it does not solve my problem. it's not what i want. :-)
before i call some function 
for example 
ReadFloat (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IniReader.aspx). i need to know that i have Float value in my STRING. That was my question.

Comment: And boost will solve it again next release with utree or Property Tree

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the *Factory* pattern, but you will need to have a root class to derive from.  For example, how is the factory to return a pointer to a `string` or a pointer to a `bool`?

How are these objects used?

Another suggestion is to have a `vector` for each type of object, and two `std::map` containers, one for functions to create the objects and another for function pointers to creation functions.
Use one of the maps to get a function for creating the item.
Use the other map to get the vector for the item.
Execute the function with passing the correct vector.

Otherwise, it's pointers to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to look at some c++ [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) [library (parser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I'm about to propose this, but here goes...

Define a simple `attribute` class which is a wrapper around `std::string` - which is your value. This class should provide conversion operators (as much as I dislike them, in this case, they could make life a little easier).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

struct attribute
{
  std::string value;

  operator bool() const { return boost::lexical_cast<bool>(value); }
  operator int() const { return boost::lexical_cast<int>(value); }
  operator unsigned int() const { return boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(value); }
  operator double() const { return boost::lexical_cast<double>(value); }
  operator std::string() const { return value; }
};

int main(void)
{
  attribute a = { "foo" };
  attribute b = { "10" };

  std::string sa = a;
  int sb = b;
  unsigned int su = b;

  std::cout << sa << std::endl;
  std::cout << sb << std::endl;
  std::cout << su << std::endl;
}
```

So here, the type of the variable you are assigning to determines the conversion that is applied. Now the **major problem** with this approach is that if there is no direct conversion operator, the compiler will select the best match - which may not be always what you want. So to be safe, define all the conversions you need and you may be okay.

Next, store this `attribute` along with your string key in the map (NOTE: you'll have to implement default ctor/copy ctor/assign op etc. as the defaults are not safe). If you cannot be bothered with the latter, store a smart pointer in the map, e.g.

```
std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<attribute> > attributes;
```

Now your interface should accept a key and return the `attribute`, e.g.

```
attribute const& get(std::string const& some_key)
{
  map<>::iterator it = attributes.find(some_key);
  return *it->second; 
}

bool bv = get(some_key); // automatically converted to bool (if lexical_cast doesn't throw)
```